# How do I automatically redirect people from my Blogger blog?

Tags: redirects, blogger

[My blog](http://thegeektechblog.blogspot.com) is a Blogger blog and I'm going to be moving it soon to a .com domain and a Wordpress site. How do I redirect people (and links) to my new site?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible I'm afraid, best you can do is a [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) or a javascript redirect, because a 301 has to happen *before* the http headers are sent and that's not possible in this case.

With a meta refresh you'll need implement [rel cannonical](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394) (cross domain rel's are acceptable) to solve Google's potential duplicate content issue.

You might find the [blogger-301-redirect plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blogger-301-redirect/) or the [seo-blogger-to-wordpress-301-redirector](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/seo-blogger-to-wordpress-301-redirector/) for wordpress handy in this situation.